# How to print the console value in my Eclipse?

Tags: java, console

My Application is in some other folder, I call that function, the output is printed in my console.

How can I get the value from the console?

Comment: You got two different answers - your question is not clear. You should be more specific as to what you want to do

Comment: Actually My Requirements is to print the log details. Am printing that log fields using some properties,that log fields is printed in my Console.. Now i want to take the console value and send it through somewhere..is it possible to take the console output by java coding? – Elakkiya 0 secs ago edit

Comment: Are you able to look at the code in the application? Can't you take the part of the code that outputs to console and put the same string or value in an `ArrayList<String>` so you can use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. However, you can use this code snippet to get line of text from console (it also works in Eclipse):

```
String val = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
System.out.println("val = " + val);
```

Comment: Actually My Requirements is to print the log details. Am printing that log fields using some properties,that log fields is printed in my Console.. Now i want to take the console value and send it through somewhere..is it possible to take the console output by java coding?

Comment: And Then i didnt used any command to print the log fields,that is automatically generated by property file..now i want to take that statement from console

Comment: I have never heard about such solution for Eclipse. However it is possible with Java to run some other process and capture its output. Here is a tutorial: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html From my experience, it is much better to use some logging Facade (SLF4J, Commons logging) and then properly configure appenders (in your case configure 2 appenders: 1) standard console appender 2) file appender).

Comment: Sir i dunno about the SLF4J.My Requirements is to receive the log Statements without using properties.Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to redirect the console text into a log/text file under eclipse. If you are running a web-based application, possibility is that you already have a .log file configured some where. You can simply open this log file and look for messages.

In case of pure java application however, most of the output is showin in the eclipse console unless you configure a redirect.

Pull up the "Debug" or "Run" dialogs where you configured your main class. Select the java application you want to run. If you dont have an entry under "java applications", you might have to create one. On the right hand side of the screen, select the "Common" tab. Check the "File" checkbox and mention a physical path+filename in the input textbox. You are all set! Open the specified file in your fav text editor.

Comment: Actually My Requirements is to print the log details. Am printing that log fields using some properties,that log fields is printed in my Console.. Now i want to take the console value and send it through somewhere..is it possible to take the console output by java coding? – Elakkiya 0 secs ago edit

Answer (score 2):

You select the text in your console, right-click and select copy.

Now you can paste the text you've copied.

Comment: Actually My Requirements is to print the log details. Am printing that log fields using some properties,that log fields is printed in my Console.. Now i want to take the console value and send it through somewhere..is it possible to take the console output by java coding? – Elakkiya 0 secs ago edit

Answer (score 2):

Your function may be using `System.out.println()` to print out a variable to the console. To get this value from your function, you need to make your function return it e.g.

```
public int myFunction(){
   int val=42;
   System.out.println(val);
   return val;
}

//call it like this:
int result = myFunction();
```

Comment: Actually My Requirements is to print the log details. Am printing that log fields using some properties,that log fields is printed in my Console.. Now i want to take the console value and send it through somewhere..is it possible to take the console output by java coding?